# Error when install joomla what is the reason

Tags: php, joomla

I want to install Joomla on my website but I get these errors , what to do please?

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/u806493334/public_html/includes/joomla.php on line 844 
Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/minhdiep/public_html/v1/includes/version.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u806493334:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/u806493334/public_html/includes/joomla.php on line 71 
Warning: require_once(/home/minhdiep/public_html/v1/includes/version.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/u806493334/public_html/includes/joomla.php on line 71
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/minhdiep/public_html/v1/includes/version.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /home/u806493334/public_html/includes/joomla.php on line 71
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've got to make some changes to your PHP.ini file.  Have a look at the docs at [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir).